# LTSpice how to change background color plot OSX Mac Macbook?

Tags: ltspice, osx

How do I change the background color of the plot in LTSpice on OSX? There is no color setting when right clicking in the plot nor is there any settings in the "tab" of the program...

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to change the background color of a plot in LTSpice on OSX (and other Apple OS's) by pressing the hammer to open a menu. Select the Waveforms tab and press *Configure Colors*. From there you can select *Background* from a drop-down menu called *Selected Item*. Configure as you wish!

(1) Press the hammer.

(2) Select Waveforms tab.

(3) Press *Configure Colors*.

(4) Select *Background* from the drop-down menu and configure.

Answer (score 0):

For the OSX version of LTSpice I have created a new color theme manager available here: https://github.com/johan162/themeltspice

Easiest way to install is via homebrew

```
brew tap johan162/themeltspice
brew install themeltspice
```

You can find the documentation on the github page.